# Location of HTML file in wordpress for editing purposes

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, firebug

I just finished learning CSS and I trying to edit the format of the footer of the wordpress based website.

I can spot its code from firebug extension but dont know whether the HTML file is located in the wordpress directory so that I can edit it. Can anyone help. I am new to web development.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. Your wordpress website will be using a theme. There are so many different ways to build a theme, so I can't tell you where the HTML for the footer will be. Theme files are located at /wp-content/themes/

Comment: Right. I have it running on the server. Lets say I want to edit the footer column heading of "Join Us" at www.ospreydubai.ae. Its very easy to locate it via firebug but i cannot find its code (That h5 tag which i need to change to h3)

Comment: See the [Firebug FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq#Where_is_the_source_shown_inside_the_HTML_panel_located) and read the [WordPress manual](http://en.support.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-content/themes/your-theme/footer.php

There should be the PHP/HTML for the footer.

It is not always that easy to find where the html comes from.
e.g. : You can have a widget area in your footer.php and then your html comes from the widget you added to this area.

It also depends on the theme you use.
But mostly you'll see a header.php/footer.php/index.php file.

Comment: yes. in case of footer its easy. like i would just try to located its file but isnt there any way i can just get the whole html in one page. especially, when I add plugins, its hard to locate the file

Comment: @OspreyHomes No this depends on the theme you use. And there isn't a html file because it is generated by the PHP and Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way to find HTML code or text is here: [String Locator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/). just download this plugin and type the html code or text you need to find out and you can easily know the exact location of the particular code or text and after that you can easily change it.

Cheers!